# Parsing a JSON string for AJAX GET requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2 3.3.1](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#events), and on an event I get access to the changed elements in my multiple text input that serves as a place to create and delete tags for use on my website. I'm having trouble iterating over the objects returned in the event handler. Specifically, I want to do this because I want access to the individual tags, and the event handler return parameter contains these objects organized by whether the tags were added or removed. So, this is excellent. But everything I've tried fails.

```
.on("change", function(e) { 
    alert(JSON.stringify({val:e.val, added:e.added, removed:e.removed}));
    var added = JSON.stringify({added:e.added});
    $.each(added, function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/db-interaction/tags.php',
            data: {
                'action': 'addtag',
                'q': this
            },
            type: 'get',
            success: function(output) {

            }
        });             
    });
```

The command on the second line above

`alert(JSON.stringify({val:e.val, added:e.added, removed:e.removed}));`

displays this string

`{"val":["newtag"],"added":{"id":"newtag","count":"0"}}` in an alert.

In this case, I had just added the word 'newtag' as a tag. I'd like to be able to iterate over these items in this inner list.

I've also tried a double nested loop, like shown below, but I get the same error. I'm not certain what structure the JSON string requires.

```
$.each(added, function(){
      $.each(this, function(){
```

The ajax request doesn't seem to execute but I can't locate the bug. The success function doesn't execute and there is an error in the firebug console. It says `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand e`, pointing to the jquery script. It's my bug, I'm sure. Probably to do with the way I'm handling the event handler parameter 'e', but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the tag script. FWIW, the addNewTag() method works in other use cases.

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once "../inc/constants.inc.php";
include_once "../inc/class.tags.inc.php";
$tags = new Tags();

if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['LoggedIn']==1)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['action']) )
    {
        switch($_POST['action'])
        {
            case 'addtag':
                echo $tags->addNewTag();
                break;
            case 'removetag':
                echo $tags->removeTag();
                break;
            case 'getalltags':
                echo $tags->getAllTags();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if(!empty($_GET['action']))
    {
        switch($_GET['action'])
        {
            case 'addtag':
                echo $tags->addNewTag();
                break;
            case 'removetag':
                echo $tags->removeTag();
                break;
            case 'getalltags':
                echo $tags->getAllTags();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

?>
```

And the addNewTag() method, which works well in other cases:

```
/**
 * Adds a new tag, increment uses_count if it already exists
 * 
 * 
 */
public function addNewTag($name=NULL)
{
    if ($name === NULL){
        if (isset($_POST['q']) )
            $u = $_POST['q'];
        else if (isset($_GET['q']))
            $u = $_GET['q'];
    }
    else{
        $u = $name;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tags(name,uses_count) VALUES (:term,1) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uses_count=uses_count+1;";
    if($stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql)) 
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(":term", $u, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }
```

Can anyone help me out? If it would be of use, I could describe the other things I've tried and why they haven't worked.

Comment: on the script you are working from.. you could use `json_encode($var);` to parse a php array into json for your Jquery

Comment: `var added = JSON.stringify({added:e.added});` gives you a string, I guessing you wanted an object i.e. `var added = {added:e.added};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$.each(e.added, function(key, value){
    alert(key + ' - ' + value )
    $.ajax({
        url: '/db-interaction/tags.php',
        data: {
            'action': 'addtag',
            'q': this
        },
        type: 'get',
        success: function(output) {

        }
    });             
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XsgMc/)

Comment: .. I don't think this was the problem.

Comment: This was it. Thanks @Arun, the key value parameters were exactly what I was looking for. Not used to that.